# Merge web-control and web-controls

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

StackOverflow has 14 questions with the `web-control` tag.  I recommend merging them with `web-controls`.

Comment: Appears there's already a `webcontrol` -> `web-controls` - so added a syn. for `web-control` -> `web-controls` as well.